# iOS, Xcode, How to get numbers called from a database using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode, numbers

Basically, I'm trying to make use of Core Data in order to bring in numbers for a flash card iOS app that I'm in the process of making. I need the numbers to be called from the Database that I'm using (Core Data), and I know I'm supposed to be in the viewdidload to call them. The numbers themselves are labels, requiring an NSNumber. Could anyone help me regarding the correct function and it's location?

Apologies for the lack of code, I'm running a VMware and can't copy and paste from the Mavericks VM!

Also, I'm rather new to iOS coding :/

Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in understanding your Question,

You need to know how to store and retrieve data for NSNumber object.

You can give `Integer` type for the `Attribute` you want to store in the `Entity` in CoreData and then retrieve that using `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]`

```
    NSInteger value = <your coredata value>;//you will get this using NSFetchedResultsController
    NSNumber number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an entity named `Card` and that entity have an attribute named `flashCardNumber` then you can find your entity and then search for a specific `flashCardNumber` like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //Your context
Card *card;

NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"flashCardNumber == %@", numberToSearcFor]];

if ([context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]) {
    card = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];
}
```